# expo init not working because of nodejs version

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-S5a0eXPoc
It's a React Native tutorial video.

I have installed expo-cli and tried to run
expo init projectName

But this is failing because of the below issue

[image]

Can anyone help me on this issue. What do I need to do here?

I am using Windows 10 laptop and my current node version is v13.12.0 and npm version is 6.14.4

Comment: Latest version of the `expo-cli` is 3.23.1, which one do you have installed?

Comment: I am using 3.23.1

Comment: This might happen because you have more than one version of node installed. Perhaps take a look at the [Expo Forum](https://forums.expo.io/) to find more answers.